# Hbase Stargate returns scrambled values

Tags: rest, hbase, stargate

I'm trying out Hbase Stargate as a REST server that's bundled with my Hbase installation.  It's simple to get up and running, but I'm wondering how to view actual row data?  When I perform a GET request in my REST client, I am returned with scrambled values:

**GET localhost:8282/article/row1/**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CellSet>
<Row key="cm93MQ==">
<Cell column="Y2Y6QXJ0aWNsZUlE" timestamp="1357592601561">MQ==</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6Q2FwRGF0ZQ==" timestamp="1357592790624">dG9kYXk=</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6Q292ZXJhZ2U=" timestamp="1357592715068">U2FtcGxlIENvdmVyYWdl</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6RW5jb2Rpbmc=" timestamp="1357592773388">VVRGLTg=</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6TENvZGU=" timestamp="1357592744929">ZW4=</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6TGFuZw==" timestamp="1357592760758">RW5nbGlzaA==</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6TmF0aXZlTmFtZQ==" timestamp="1357592681884">U2FtcGxlIE5hdGl2ZSBOYW1l</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6UHViRGF0ZQ==" timestamp="1357592786561">dG9kYXk=</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6U291cmNlSUQ=" timestamp="1357592732763">MQ==</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6U291cmNlSUQ=" timestamp="1357592663427">U2FtcGxlIFNvdXJjZSBJRA==</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6U291cmNlVHlwZQ==" timestamp="1357592701595">U2FtcGxlIFNvdXJjZSBUeXBl</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6VGV4dA==" timestamp="1357592802878">U2FtcGxlIFRleHQ=</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6VGl0bGU=" timestamp="1357592629292">U2FtcGxlIFRpdGxl</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6VHJUaXRsZQ==" timestamp="1357592640605">U2FtcGxlIFRyVGl0bGU=</Cell>
<Cell column="Y2Y6VXJs" timestamp="1357592616187">aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29t</Cell>
</Row>
</CellSet>
```

I did reference the WIKI which also shows examples with scrambled results: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate#A5, but I cannot find any information on how to decode it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to decode your result is by using the base64 function from your shell. eg.

```
echo "cm93MQ==" | base64 -d
```