# Is there any guideline to connect hbase with ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, hbase

I'm a new for ionic app. Now i have a problem to connect hbase with ionic app. I can connect hbase with jsp. But i think ionic app don't use jsp. I don't understand what i should go now. Is there any guideline for this problem?

**ADDED**

I found some documentations for using HBase REST API. I show you guys several steps. Also you can look over the whole things to here.

1. Install `curl` on your machine

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install curl
   ```
2. Run a HBase REST API server as background process. The default port is 8080 but i was using the port.

   ```
   $ ./HBASE_HOME/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start rest -p 7878
   ```
3. For instance, you get a data for a specific key from HBase using `curl` like below.

   ```
   $ curl -vi -X GET -H 'Accept: text/xml' '192.168.0.1:7878/mytable/rowkey1'
   ```
4. In my case the data was encoded. But i don't know how to get the data without encoding. I show you how to decode this data using `base64`

   ```
   $ echo "aGFwcHkgZGF5" | base64 -d
   ```

**References**

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/admin_hbase_rest_api.html

[Hbase Stargate returns scrambled values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207227/hbase-stargate-returns-scrambled-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way where you can do this is, you need to develop **Restful API** where it interacts with the **HBase** database and use that API to fetch and put data (**CRUD**) from your Ionic 2 app.

Comment: Using Restful API is better than connection directly?

Comment: Yes, That is the best approach (`restful API`) and is recommended one.